# I had an issue in creating a JBOD pool

Tags: jbod

So I created a JBOD volume pool with NAS TS-453Be.

Now initially I don't understand how JBOD works after it is created, but there we're an issue that makes me check one of the disk by removing them while the system is still on. It was a JBOD of 1 TB not that much, accumulation of 2 (500gb) HDD. With that small maneuver I did by removing one of the disc while the NAS was still on, the system cannot rebuild the JBOD volume from the two disks, thus rendering the JBOD pool inactive and unaccessible.

Now I tried to rebuild the JBOD, but the system shows this message, "Failed to recover storage pool. Possible reasons: Someone inserted new disks, or the data is damaged. To continue, insert the original disks into the NAS and recover the pool again, or delete the pool and create a new one."

Regaining this has simply become out of the option for some reason, from the manual too, it said that it is required to create a new JBOD pool.

Now come to the question, can I create the new JBOD with the same HDD, that is occupied(/has data), and not lose any of those data? Because the HDD is still in good health. It just wont read the data. How should I do this?

Comment: JBOD is Just a Bunch Of Drives. There is no redundancy. Once it is broken (disk failed/pulled/etc.), it is irrecoverable. If you needed failure tolerance, you need to use RAID1/4/5/6, not a JBOD.